# Codemirror not compatible with Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: codemirror

I want to use Jquery Autocomplete for my codemirror editor. But Looks like its not compatible with  it. I have following code working to display the list of options inside a textarea when the user  hits the  ctrl-enter key.

```
 $("#textareaCodemirror").autocomplete({
   source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
   minLength: 0
 });

 $('#textareaCodemirror').keydown(function (e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 13)) {
   $("#textareaCodemirror").autocomplete("search","");
  }
 });
```

It works fine. The issue is sometimes when I hit ctrl-enter,the browser hangs for a some time and  then I get a dialog box that asks me if I want to enter code here or continue the script.

The message in the  dialog box says the following:

```
  "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
 Script: "location1/codemirror/js/codemirror.js:958 "
```

In the above message,codemirror.js is another library I am using.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi , do you find answer to your problem ? if you do can put an example on js to show me how i can use codemirror with jquary for autocomplete ... thanks in advance